# Comparing two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare the values of two columns with the following code:

```
if df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']:
total_bet += 1
```

It is returning the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: You should check your logic firstly, what do you want to achieve? `df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']` returns a logic series while if expects a logic value.

Answer (score 4):

First, the result of `df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']` is also a Series consist of boolean value, e.g., `[True, True, False, ...]`, so you get error message `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`.

So what should you do? That's depended on your application.

(1) if your intention is to count the number of `True` condition, then

```
 total_bet = sum(df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread'])
```

(2) if your intention is to increase `total_bet` when all comparation of `df['predicted_spead'] > df['vegas_spread']` is true, then

```
if (df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']).all() is True:
    total_bet += 1
```

(3) if `total_bet` is also a vector, and your intention is to record each comparation, then

```
total_bet = total_bet + (df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread'])
```

I guess option (1) is what you need. Thanks.